# Finding Files in a Git Bash Terminal

Tags: git-bash, gnu-findutils

I am currently using [Git Bash](http://msysgit.github.io/) to navigate file directories and edit files. I want to know if there's a command to search the current directory and all directories in it for a file name.

Comment: `git` and `bash` are two totally different things. `bash` is the Unix (or Linux) shell. `git` is a software source control program. As others have answered, there's a Unix/Linux command `find` which does what you want, and it's independent of `git` and works in any available shell, including `bash`.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it comes with the [find utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html). To recursively search for a file named "somefile.txt" starting from the current working directory, the following should work:

```
find . -name somefile.txt
```

Comment: see answer by @misja111  comment if using windows: Use /bin/find not just find.

Comment: On git for Win 2.28.0 `$ find . -name "something"` does anyhow not work recursively. Can anybody confirm or clarify?

Comment: @woodz Your find might be pointing to the Windows version. See misja111's answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Git Bash on Windows, then it might well be that `find` will point to the Find tool that comes with Windows and not to the one provided by Git Bash. The [Windows Find tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find) searches for text *within* a file or files, similar to Unix's `grep`.

You can verify by executing `which find`. If it points to your Windows folder, it's not the Unix tool.

To be sure that you are using the Unix `find` from the Git Bash shell, type `/bin/find`. Now the `-name` parameter will work as shown in other answers.

Comment: I'm using git for Windows and `find . -name somefile.txt` does work. For instance, I try `find . -name *.js` and it finds all .js files recursively. It took a while initially, because, I don't know, Windows?

Comment: I had lots of trouble with a failing AppVeyor test that used `find` in the git bash. Thousand thanks for your answer! It saved my day. `bin/find` for the win!

Comment: A  `which find` on Git Bash gives me `/usr/bin/find` instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find e.g. all java file names containing the word 'Test', recursively from the current directory, you can use

```
git ls-files '*Test*.java'
```

To search for all files whose contents includes containing the word "FIXME", you can use

```
git grep 'FIXME'
```

Answer (score 3):

Git Bash is a `bash` shell underneath, and as such all standard Unix utilities will be available. The standard `find` utility will work fine:

```
$ find . -name filename.java
```

will find `filename.java` in your directory/subdirectories. Note that you have to escape wildcarding, otherwise the shell itself will interpret this e.g.

```
$ find . -name \*.java
```

will give you all the `.java` files

`find` is powerful, but can be complex to use. Check out a tutorial [here](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Find.html).

Comment: Wow, this answer *completely* lost out to [the currently top-voted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21438636/95852) because it was apparently 15 seconds too slow. I gotta give this one an upvote (its first one?!) because it provides a useful superset of the information in that other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run this command on the git shell:

```
find / -name 'filename-you-want-search-regex-allowed'
```

This will search all the files below `/` across file system.